# Does using the mikvah for conversion make you tahor for marriage?

Tags: women, conversion-to-judaism, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, mikvah-ritual-bath, niddah

Does one become tahor for all purposes by using a mikvah for a single purpose? For example, if a giyores converts in the mikvah, is she then tahor for marriage? I ask because the converts I know have never been required to count seven clean days, make bedikas, etc., before going to the mikvah, and according to one thing I heard, they may even be able to tovel while menstruating (not sure about this). This would suggest the immersion is not l'chatchila kosher for taharas hamishpacha. But shouldn't a mikvah dip in theory accomplish full purity, that is, by a universal standard? Please discuss.

Comment: "tahor for marriage" Do you refer to a wedding or general "taharas hamishpacha"? What sort of requirements do you think a wedding has that this would serve?

Comment: @DoubleAA Either?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think that question is exactly the same as this one by any means. I'm interested because people I know who converted and people I know who got married had wildly different processes for preparing for mikvah re: menstruation

Comment: Still puzzled by this inyan since learning that a woman can have even a giyur l'chumra during her period. Surely she wouldn't be tahor for marriage after that?

Comment: She would be Safek Tahor until she bleeds further. The Safek was if she was Jewish. So lets look at the two sides: if she was Jewish, then her earlier bleeding had made her a Niddah and dipping doesn't help since she hasn't counted days/bedikot; if she wasn't Jewish, then the previous bleeding doesn't make her a Niddah and after the dip she's Jewish and Tehorah, until she bleeds further when she becomes a Niddah.

Comment: @DoubleAA Right. Your side 1 is why I bring this point. (others are saying she would definitely be tahor for marriage after a tvila for conversion, but because of the giyur l'chumra example, I say she wouldn't necesarily be)

Comment: And furthermore I'd say that if in principle there is a safek about the Yiddishkeit of everyone/anyomne, we couldn't rely on this tevila for marriage